# What's the best way to vertically align content within Bootstrap 4 grid columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have the following elements with Bootsrap 4(.3.1) classes:

```
  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Copyright &copy;
      </div>
      <div class="col text-right">
        <a class="">Back to top</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

The height of `<footer>` is 100px and I'd like the content fo the cols to sit veritcally in the center of the element.

I've tried adding `d-flex align-items-center` to the elements (trying container, row and cols in turn) but didn't get any results.

Will I have to scrap the grid classes all together and re-do this with flex classes? Or does anyone know of a way Bootstrap can acheive this out-of-the-box using it's own classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to adding `d-flex align-items-center` to the `footer` and `flex-grow-1` to the `row` class - see demo below:

```css
footer {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<footer class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="row flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col">
      Copyright &copy;
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
      <a class="">Back to top</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the height to the row. and use align-items-center to vericaly align the flex-items i.e, col

```css
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <footer class=" container-fluid">
    <div class="footer row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        Copyright &copy;
      </div>
      <div class="col text-right">
        <a class="">Back to top</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```